# How to write a python script that runs an html file in background behind other windows? (without third party)

Tags: python, html, background

I would like to have an html file **behave** as my windows 10 background. However, **I cannot use third party software on my system**. I would like to instead use python (or similar scripting) to create a no-header browser window that operates the html blocks/elements but maintains itself behind all other windows [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kupwY.png). I know this has been solved by many in third party software, but my system will not allow me to install them. I would like to solve this problem with a python launcher script if possible. Any script elements or reference articles that would help me get going would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: You can't install 3rd party software, but are allowed to *write and execute* arbitrary software?!?

Comment: Questions where the described problem is a whole project are considered too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Scott, yes they are controlled systems from third party downloads off the internet. But python and console scripts are authorized in-system. Many of our tools are python based. Klaus, I am not expecting a walkthrough solution. I just want to know where to get started from someone who may be more familiar with python solutions.